# How do I add both the UNIQUE and NOT NULL constraints during table creation?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to add multiple constraints to a column **during table creation**, but I am not sure how to correctly add the NOT NULL and UNIQUE constraints during it.

```sql
SQL> CREATE TABLE BOOK_STORES
  2  (Store_ID NUMBER(8)
  3  ,Name VARCHAR2(30)
  4  ,Contact VARCHAR2(30)
  5  ,Rep_ID VARCHAR(5)
  6  ,CONSTRAINT Store_id_PK PRIMARY KEY (Store_ID)
  7  ,CONSTRAINT Name_UN UNIQUE (Name), Name_NN NOT NULL (Name));
```

This is what I have attempted so far. I am new to Oracle and SQL. I was expecting this to apply both constraints to the "Name" column so that is would not accept null values or duplicate values.

But I am receiving this error:

```
,CONSTRAINT Name_UN UNIQUE (Name), Name_NN NOT NULL (Name))
                                                  *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: You have omitted the `CONSTRAINT` keyword for your `Name_NN` constraint.  You need that if you want to name the constraint.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It also needs to be an in-line constraint for `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an in-line constraint for `NOT NULL`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE BOOK_STORES (
  Store_ID NUMBER(8)
, Name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
, Contact VARCHAR2(30)
, Rep_ID VARCHAR(5)
, CONSTRAINT book_stores__Store_id__PK PRIMARY KEY (Store_ID)
, CONSTRAINT book_stores__Name__UN UNIQUE (Name)
);
```

or, to name the constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE BOOK_STORES (
  Store_ID NUMBER(8)
, Name VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT book_stores__Name__NN NOT NULL
, Contact VARCHAR2(30)
, Rep_ID VARCHAR(5)
, CONSTRAINT book_stores__Store_id__PK PRIMARY KEY (Store_ID)
, CONSTRAINT book_stores__Name__UN UNIQUE (Name)
);
```

or, out-of-line, using a `CHECK` constraint (rather than a `NOT NULL` constraint) to check that it is not null:

```sql
CREATE TABLE BOOK_STORES (
  Store_ID NUMBER(8)
, Name VARCHAR2(30)
, Contact VARCHAR2(30)
, Rep_ID VARCHAR(5)
, CONSTRAINT book_stores__Store_id__PK PRIMARY KEY (Store_ID)
, CONSTRAINT book_stores__Name__UN UNIQUE (Name)
, CONSTRAINT book_stores__Name__NN CHECK (name IS NOT NULL)
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-5S0c_pw)